# pushType=gcm deviceToken=Undefined

Tags: android, push-notification, devicetoken

We have a problem with push notification on Android devices,
When pushType is gcm and deviceToken be undifined, we can't send notification to these devices.
Some our users have  this problem. (about 10%)
How we can resolve this problem? (without activing google account)

public class ParseApplication extends Application {

```
final static String APPLICATION_ID=***
final static String CLIENT_ID=***

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ParseCrashReporting.enable(getApplicationContext());

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());

    Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), APPLICATION_ID, CLIENT_ID);

    Log.d("Parse Initialize","Start");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    String  device_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
    ParseInstallation installation=ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
    installation.put("UniqueId",device_id);
    installation.put("apiVersion",android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
    installation.saveInBackground();
}
```

Comment: If you don't have device token, you can't send notifications. You need to check why you don't get the device token in GCM registration.